# Python regex replace each match with itself plus a new line

Tags: python, regex

I have a long regex with many alternations and I want to be able to replace each match from the regex with itself followed by a new line ('\n').

What is the most efficient way to do so with re.sub()?

Here is a simple example:

```
s = 'I want to be able to replace many words, especially in this sentence, since it will help me solve by problem. That makes sense right?'

pattern = re.compile(r'words[,]|sentence[,]|problem[.]')

for match in matches:
    re.sub(pattern, match + '\n', match)
```

I know this for loop will not work, I am just hoping to clarify what I am trying to solve here. Thanks in advance for any help. I may be missing something very straightforward.

Comment: Maybe `s = re.sub(pattern, "\\g<0>\n", s)`.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/FF0vL0

Comment: Ok will do. Is there not a simple way to iterate through each match object and replace it with itself plus a newline character? I'm not sure if Python can translate between match objects and strings, which may be the problem.

Comment: Are you storing the matches and then replacing them?

Comment: That is what I would like to do I guess. I have five different matching options in one regex formula for identifying the ends of sentences (for my specific application) and I would just like to replace each match that it finds with itself plus a newline character. I only have one capturing group, which would be the full matches themselves.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/TccdBH, you do not need a capturing group here.

Comment: Why don't you use `re.subn()`?

Comment: No need to use `subn()` if you aren't trying to limit number of matches

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just got a chance to try that out. Works like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To replace a whole match with itself you may use a replacement backreference `\g<0>`. However, you want to replace and store the matches inside a variable. You need to pass a callback method as a replacement argument to `re.sub`, and return the whole match value (`match.group()`) with a newline appended to the value:

```
import re
matches = []                          # Variable to hold the matches
def repl(m):                          # m is a match data object
    matches.append(m.group())         # Add a whole match value
    return "{}\n".format(m.group())   # Return the match and a newline appended to it

s = 'I want to be able to replace many words, especially in this sentence, since it will help me solve by problem. That makes sense right?'
pattern = re.compile(r'words[,]|sentence[,]|problem[.]')
s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)

print(s)
print(matches)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UYnpIb)

Answer (score 0):

Just like this?

```
    text ='I want to be able to replace many words, especially in this sentence, since it will help me solve by problem. That makes sense right?'
    text_list = tex t.replace('.',',').strip(',|.|?').split(',')
    ##Remove the beginning and end symbols.And split by ','
    print (text_list)
    for i in text_list:
        ii=i.split(',')
        print(ii)
```

Result

```
    ['I want to be able to replace many words', ' especially in this sentence', ' since it will help me solve by problem', ' That makes sense right']
    ['I want to be able to replace many words']
    [' especially in this sentence']
    [' since it will help me solve by problem']
    [' That makes sense right']
```

Comment: text_list = re.sub(r'[,.?]+',',',text).strip(',').split(',')

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter of re.sub can either be a string or a callable that takes in the match instance and returns a string. so do this

```
def break_line(match):
    return "\n" + match.group()

text = re.sub(pattern, break_line, text)
```